# Linking two scroll bars, slows down the mousewheel scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to link scrollbars of two scrollable divs, using jquery/javascript.

By dragging the scroll bars of those divs, scrolling works good. But, When I scroll by mousewheel, the scrolling happens dead slow.. Provided the fiddle link below, Someone help me on linking two scrollbars perfectly, that works even with mousewheel scrolls. Thanks in advance.. :) 
[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manushmanush01/txr0d05L/)

HTML:

```
<div id="left" class="linked">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Eiffel_Tower_(72_names).jpg">
</div>
<div id="right" class="linked">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Eiffel_Tower_(72_names).jpg">
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('.linked').scroll(function(){
$('.linked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
$('.linked').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get into something as an `scrollTop` endless loop. If `left` is scrolled, `right` gets scrolled, what causes `left` to scroll again and so on.

In my example it works fast as expected, although only the left one is synced.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#right').scroll(function(){
        console.log(this);
        $('#left').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());   
        $('#left').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    })
})
```

```css
#left, #right, #test { 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 400px; 
  overflow: scroll; 
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left" class="linked">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Eiffel_Tower_(72_names).jpg">
</div>
<div id="right" class="linked">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Eiffel_Tower_(72_names).jpg">
</div>
<div id="test">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Eiffel_Tower_(72_names).jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Here the mousewheel scroll will work, only when you scroll from "#right" div.  But, Its supposed to be the scroll should be worked in both divs..